# Limit $ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{t=1}^n t^2(1+R)^{-t^2} $

Tags: limits

$$
\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\displaystyle\sum_{t=1}^n t^2(1+R)^{-t^2}
$$
$R>0$. I guess that it can be solved by splitting the general like this.

$$
\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\lim}\sum_{t=1}^n{t^2\left( 1+R \right) ^{-t^2}}=\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\lim}\sum_{t=1}^n{\left[ f\left( t+1 \right) -f\left( t \right) \right]}=\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\left[ f\left( t+1 \right) -f\left( 1 \right) \right] 
$$
But it seems a little difficult to find $f(t). $

Any other methods will be appreciated too.

Comment: I don't see how it would be a telescoping sum. I don't think it will have a closed form either, based on some experimentation with WolframAlpha, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong

Comment: what is the source of this question?

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of the third theta function:

$$\vartheta_3(z,q) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2\pi i z}$$

we have that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2} = \frac{1}{2}\vartheta_3(0,x) + \frac{1}{2}$$

by exploiting the symmetries in the summation. Then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 x^{n^2-1} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial \vartheta_3}{\partial q}(0,x)$$

which means our summation in question is

$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty t^2 (1+R)^{-t^2} = \frac{1}{2(1+R)}\frac{\partial \vartheta_3}{\partial q}\left(0,\frac{1}{1+R}\right)$$

I'm not sure if we can get an answer better than that.